# number of zeroes of arbitrary function

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, real-numbers, programming

Sorry if I misused/mixed up some maths terms. I barely know any maths lingo, especially not in English.

I was thinking about programmatically solving equations (or rather, approximating their roots), and was wondering about how to guarantee an arbirtarily close approximation of every root of a function has been found. I'm only considering real numbers here, as well as only equations of the form $y=f(x)$
Here's some observations I've made:

1. This can always be guaranteed as long as the number of roots of a function can be calculated/counted and is finite (though it can take aribtrarily long to find them, once you have, you can guarantee you have all of them).
2. Inversely, the number of roots of a function can always be calculated/counted if you can approximate all of its roots and guarantee there are no other roots.
3. If this condition holds true for the continuous function $f(x)$, it also always holds true for $F(x)$

I know this condition holds true for all non-zero polinomials, since it holds true for $f(x)=ax$ where a is nonzero (see number 3 of my observations). I wonder if there are other (categories of) functions this applies to, if there's other observations to be made about this condition, and if there's maybe even a way to guarantee this condition holds true or false for an arbitrary function.

My apologies if my question is either too vague/too broad/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantely, there are several challenges that make these claims insufficient.

1. If the function is discontinuous, it may appear to have a root when in fact it does not.  For instance, consider a function f(x) = 1 for $x \gt 0$, and f(x) = -1 otherwise.  This function would appear to cross the x axis and therefore would be a candidate for a function that has a root, but no such root could be found.  In fact, any approximation method that relies on limit behaviour around the root will fail, since in the limit it always appears as though this function has a root around $x = 0$ when in fact it does not.
2. If you're talking about root finding *in principle*, then yes, for some class of functions arbitrary approximations of their roots can be found. If you're talking about doing it using a practical computer then no, this is not possible.  For instance, a function with a horizontal asymptote at $y = 0$ will appear to approach 0 but never reach it.
3. This relies heavily on root counting, which is *hard*.  For polynomials it's simple enough - the number of roots (not necessarily real) is equal to the degree.  But there are many other functions than polynomials and therefore to count their roots may be impossible.  Furthermore, you'd need some initial estimate of where the roots are, because if you just search along the x axis you might miss some if you're stepping too far.
4. I assume by $F(x)$ you mean $f(x)$'s integral.  If the function is not integrable then this is already a nonstarter.
5. I should also mention that many root finding algorithms rely on the function giving information about the fact that there is a root there.  For example, it changes sign from positive to negative and is continuous, so it must have a root.  But consider even relatively simple functions $y = sin(x) + 1, x\in[1,\pi]$.  This function has no sign changes *but has a finite number of roots* in the domain I provided.  It in fact only has roots at a very unfortunate place - the irrational $\pi$!  Approximating a root of this function would be very hard indeed, and this function is nicely continuous.  If I made it even worse, say $f(x) = 1$ except at $x = \pi$ where $f(\pi) = 0$, then this function gives absolutely no information about where its root is that an algorithm could use without knowing exactly what the function was in the first place.  Since I presume you want a general purpose algorithm, not a specific one to the function, it appears that such a thing is not possible.

For what it's worth, equation solving and root finding are the same problem.  If $y = f(x)$ and we are looking for when $y = 3$, say, then we are finding the roots of the equation $f(x) - 3 = 0$.

Comment: I'm aware some issues arise for discontinuous functions, though I was not sure they always arise for discontinious functions nor did I claim to, I'm not entirely sure what "these claims are insufficient" refers to. I'm indeed talking about in principle - I have no current intention on actually making an arbitrary root approximater, I'm merely interested in the subject. The way you answered my question it seems you think I'm making statements about certain things where I'm actually asking about them. F(x) is f(x)'s antiderivative, which is how that is written in my country, I'm not sure how...

Comment: ... it is written in English. 5) I know root finding relies on that, and I also assume it is not possible to do so for arbitrary functions. I'm just wondering to what extend root finding can be done, specifically finding every root of a function, as finding a single root is comperatively trivial (though knowing wheter there is a root to find is less so).

Comment: I suggest editing your question, then.  For example, you claim that "...this can always be guaranteed as long as..." but that is unfortunately not true.  To edit it, you should include either the classes of functions for which it can be guaranteed, or at least a suitable restriction.  For instance, I agree that it can always be guaranteed for polynomials of finite degree.

Comment: Could you explain to me why the three observations I have made are false?

Comment: Yes.  The first claim is too broad, since there are functions for which it is not true.  Therefore, it is not a guarantee at all.  It needs to be tightened to restrict the class of functions you're talking about.  You've already mentioned you know that discontinuous functions break that claim.  The second claim is fine but it is a tautology - if you know how many roots there are you know how many roots there are.  The last claim depends on the function being integrable at least, and I'm not convinced it's true.  For instance...

Comment: if $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, then its antiderivative is $F(x) = ln(x)$, which has a root while the $f(x)$ itself does not.  So it is a dubious claim...

Comment: as for the first claim, if you know the number of roots you can guarantee that once you've found them you have found all of them. I'm not nessecarily talking about actually being able to find them all, just about being able to confirm that you have found all of them when you do (ie there is no possibility of more roots existing). As for the other claim, I didn't claim that it's guaranteed that it holds true for f'(x) if it does for f(x) - I only claimed it the other way around, for the very simple reason that f(x)=0 does not satisfy the condition while f(x)=1 does.

Comment: though now that you mention it I'm not 100% if that claim holds true if there is a function f(x) which satisfies the condition, but which has a hole (I think it still works with vertical asymptotes though, but tbh I'm not 100% sure. Keep in mind I'm not a mathamatician and honestly wouldn't know where to even begin to prove this, it's just what I've observed. I'm certain it works for all continuous functions though).

Comment: I edited #3 since I agree it is a dubious claim when it comes to non-continuous functions.

Comment: The second claim isn't that useful, though I thought I'd mention it just in case there was a way to find all roots of a function without counting them.